# Symantec Endpoint Protection Virus Definitions

Tags: windows-server-2003, malware, symantec, symantec-endpoint-protection

I have done some Googling but I cannot get a definitive answer certainly not from the Symantec KB.

I have a Virtualised Win 2003R2 server 32bit.
It has been provisioned to me with Symantec Endpoint Protection 11.0.62xxx CLIENT (not a definitions server)

the directory C:\Program Files\Common Files\Symantec Shared\VirusDefs is 750MB

IT doesn't contain .tmp directories so it is NOT a corrupt definitions server.
IT does contain directories named with a date pattern YYYYMMDD.xxx

Some of these folders are 12 months old and I would like to recover the space. The sysmantect forums are full of this stuff but a lot of the postings contain links back to documents that are not specific to End Point Protection Client.

It appears that I should be able to delete the older folders and all will be OK. with a service restart however there is a warning about having Live Update Administrator Installed

> Firstly I have no idea if I have this installed how to I check and
>   secondly can I just ditch these old files and restart?

I have followed some instructions found on the Symantec site and assumed that the response from Nixphoe would resolve my issue.
It appears that as I am on a provisioned VM from a central IT unit I cannot run the Symantec commands from the Run prompt as my admin creds to get me in. (smc -stop)
Basically I need to claw back some Diskspace from the c: drive which is being filed up with WSUS patches and Symantec files. I have managed to delete one symantec cache through the live update control panel and recovered 470Mb

> I suppose my last question for those more experienced than myself is,
>   can I simply remove say the two oldest virus definition folders
>   without completely foobaring the End Point protection and the server?

Answer (score 1):

Live update should show up in your add/remove programs, as well as under your Start > Programs.

Read over the [Content Cache Directory](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH106034&locale=en_US). It should be safe to clean that up. It also has a link about how to use [Client Cache Control](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH106042&locale=en_US)

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I have "Live Update" 3.3 in my add and remove programs.
I assume that this is not the Live update Administrator, am I correct?

Comment: To follow up with your follow up question above. You should be able to delete any of the cache and it would just redownload it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually defenitions are located in App Data folder in the root dirctory. 
( folder is hidden by default ) the path to the folder should be:
C:\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\CurrentVersion\Data\Definitions\VirusDefs
Depending on your setting you should have only one folder with most current definitions.
Size of the folder varies but form my experience it averages at about 400-600mb

Answering your question about deleteing defections, I would say No. As far as I know you can't delete definitions. *That one of t he problems that im facing right now*